# Flaky Wi-Fi on an Android tablet

Tags: wi-fi

We have been experiencing an odd issue with tablets that we sell, and our vendor is being no help, so we are forced to take matters into our own hands – but so far we've been unsuccessful.

Specs:

- OS: Android 5.1
- Wi-Fi: Ampak AP6255 onboard Wi-Fi module with a single band antenna.

Issue:

The device will see networks and confirm if the correct/incorrect credentials were entered in, but will almost always never connect. If the device does connect, it will not stay connected. We've swapped multiple antennas out, but the issue still occurs. On a Wi-Fi analyzer, the signal consistently dips. The only way we can stay connected to a network is to connect to a 5 GHz signal, which is very inconvenient.

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Check your environment. 2.4GHz is almost always saturated which causes interference and is very sensitive to certain signals such as Microwaves, Cordless phones, certain wireless fire alarms etc...  The best thing you can do is purchase (if you don't already have one) a Metageek Chanalyzer:
 http://www.metageek.com/products/wi-spy/?utm_expid=190328-202.Egk2FYNZQd6ZdJAUVdEvVA.0&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.metageek.com%2F.
This will definitely show you visually the state of your 2.4GHz environment.  Since 2.4GHz only has three non-overlapping channels (1, 6, 11) you may be out of luck.  5GHz may be your only solution because it has 23+ channels you can choose from.  The air quality in the 5GHz band is pretty clean.

Comment: Interesting.. Thank you for the recommendation, the Chanalyzer would paint a better picture for us of our environment. One of our customers builds specialized networks for large warehouses, so they have a testing facility they use to test new hardware, and they were not able to pick up any 2.4ghz signal. Something that I just learned is that the older chipset tablet models work perfectly, so do you think could this be a firmware issue in combination with an over-saturated environment?

Comment: @user724296 - It sure smells like a firmware issue.  But like you said, good luck getting a fix from the manufacturer.  Maybe you could use Wireshark to see where exactly the issue occurs.  It may be related to your WPA2 (if that's the encryption you are using) or maybe the authentication is getting stuck.  The sniffer will tell you exactly what the problem is.  Then you can find an AP that will work with that tablet.